# STM32 & Constant String in gcc

Tags: string, gcc, stm32

I am facing problem using strings/array of pointer to strings in flash with gcc. Controller is STM32F100VBT6 & compiler is Atollic TrueStudio v9.0.1.

When optimization are off, everything works fine, but with optimizations set to -s or anything else, garbage gets displayed on LCD. I can see that value of pointers to strings being passed are wrong although Map file correctly shows that strings as well as arrays of pointer to strings are in "rodata".
Here is the partial code...

```
#define MENU_CONFF_STR_COUNT            (12)
static const char g_strMnuPrev[]         = "[ ]Previous Menu";
static const char g_strMnuConf_F_1[]    = "[ ]PWD Enable?";
static const char g_strMnuConf_F_2[]    = "[ ]System Type";
static const char g_strMnuConf_F_3[]    = "[ ]Set Yr/Mon";
static const char g_strMnuConf_F_4[]    = "[ ]Set Serial";
static const char g_strMnuConf_F_5[]    = "[ ]Set M1";
static const char g_strMnuConf_F_6[]    = "[ ]Set M2";
static const char g_strMnuConf_F_7[]    = "[ ]Set IP-FSW";
static const char g_strMnuConf_F_8[]    = "[ ]Set IP-P1";
static const char g_strMnuConf_F_9[]    = "[ ]Set IP-P2";
static const char g_strMnuConf_F_10[]   = "[ ]Set TCON";
static const char g_strMnuConf_F_11[]   = "[ ]T Calib";
static const char* const g_a_strMnuConfF_P[MENU_CONFF_STR_COUNT] = {
    g_strMnuConf_F_1, g_strMnuConf_F_2 ,g_strMnuConf_F_3,
    g_strMnuConf_F_4, g_strMnuConf_F_5,
    g_strMnuConf_F_6, g_strMnuConf_F_7, g_strMnuConf_F_8,   
    g_strMnuConf_F_9, g_strMnuConf_F_10,
    g_strMnuConf_F_11,  g_strMnuPrev
};
// some code using string using function --> void vLCD_WriteStr_P( const char* pStr_P, INT8U x, INT8U y, BOOL fill );
vLCD_WriteStr_P( (const char*)g_strMnuConf_F_10, 0, LCD_ROW_1, TRUE );
//
// some code using array of pointer to strings -> INT8U ucHandle_Menu( const char* const* mnu_array, INT8U mnu_count )
for( ;; ) {
    switch( ucHandle_Menu( &g_a_strMnuConfF_P[0], MENU_CONFF_STR_COUNT ) ) {
    //....code handling switch()
    }
}
```

Also exact same code works perfectly with Keil.
So what am I doing wrong with gcc (Atollic Crossstudio)?

Here is code for vLCD_WriteStr_P(),

```
void vLCD_WriteStr_P( const char* pStr_P, INT8U x, INT8U y, BOOL fill )
{
    char ch;

    vLCD_SetXY( x, y );
    for( ;; ) {
        ch = *pStr_P++;
        if( !ch ) {
            break;
        }
        x++;                                                /* col++                                */
        vLCD_CmdData( LCD_DATA, ch );
    }

    if( fill ) {                                            /* fill rest of the row with 'blanks'   */
        while( LCD_COL_MAX > x ) {
            vLCD_CmdData( LCD_DATA, ' ' );
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you do not show enough code. Usually this kind of the behavior is a sign of the undefined behavior in your code, or breaking the strict aliasing rules - which may lead to abnormal execution with optimizations on.

Comment: As @P__J__ said, the code you've provided doesn't explain your thesis. You suggest that it's the strings being corrupted, whereas later you mention writing to LCD. Displaying data on LCD is a much more complex task (and often, parts of it are also time sensitive) than handling strings. Personally I'd suggest looking into functions handling LCD all the way down to writes to registers or memory mapped region - depending on how your LCD communication is implemented.

Comment: LCD(HD44780) initialization is fine. If gcc optimizations are turned off, everything is ok, including string display. With optimizations on, pointer deref to strings in flash, gives garbled display, while strings in RAM fine again.

Comment: Can you minimise the program, so it's as small as possible while still showing these symptoms? Then post the complete source.